# Yandex map, как добавить функцию Zoom?

Tags: javascript, html, yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте, есть код карты яндекса

```
ymaps.ready(init);
var myMap, 
    myPlacemark;

function init() {
  myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.76, 37.64],

  });
  myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([51.841718, 55.1185161],

                                    { 
    hintContent: "Москва!",
    balloonContent: "Северное сияние Офис компании <br>тел. +7 (987) 850-77-33"
  });

  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
  myPlacemark.balloon.open();
}
```

Как добавить функцию zoom, чтобы отрегулировать крупность карты? Спасибо

Comment: "отрегулировать" - поставить изначальный масштаб карты или же добавить возможность на клиенте приближать и уменьшать карту?

Comment: @Cheg Поставить нужный масштаб. С уважением

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли указать `zoom` в настройках при инициализации вашей карты.

Рабочий пример:

```js
ymaps.ready(init);
var myMap,
  myPlacemark;

function init() {
  myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [51.841718, 55.1185161],
    zoom: 7
  });
  myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([51.841718, 55.1185161],

    {
      hintContent: "Москва!",
      balloonContent: "Северное сияние Офис компании <br>тел. +7 (987) 850-77-33"
    });

  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
  myPlacemark.balloon.open();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает